# System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vpn

Hello I am working on VPN in C# this is my code

```
VpnManagementAgent vpnManagementAgent = new VpnManagementAgent();
        VpnManagementAgent mgr = vpnManagementAgent;
        VpnNativeProfile profile = new VpnNativeProfile()
        {
            AlwaysOn = false,
            NativeProtocolType = VpnNativeProtocolType.IpsecIkev2,
            ProfileName = "MyConnection",
            RememberCredentials = true,
            RequireVpnClientAppUI = true,
            RoutingPolicyType = VpnRoutingPolicyType.SplitRouting,
            TunnelAuthenticationMethod = VpnAuthenticationMethod.Certificate,
            UserAuthenticationMethod = VpnAuthenticationMethod.Mschapv2,
        };
        profile.Servers.Add("serveAddress");
        VpnManagementErrorStatus profileStatus = await mgr.AddProfileFromObjectAsync(profile);
        PasswordCredential credentials = new PasswordCredential
        {
            UserName = "username",
            Password = "Abc",
        };
        VpnManagementErrorStatus connectStatus = await mgr.ConnectProfileWithPasswordCredentialAsync(profile, credentials);
```

i add all this code on button action. now when i start VPN connection this line throw exception

```
VpnManagementErrorStatus profileStatus = await mgr.AddProfileFromObjectAsync(profile);
```

Exception is

```
 System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))'
```

StackTrace:

```
at Windows.Networking.Vpn.VpnManagementAgent.AddProfileFromObjectAsync(IVpnProfile profile)
at App1.MainPage.<Button_Click>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\Users\HP\source\repos\StarkVPnTesting\App1\MainPage.xaml.cs:line 62
```

Comment: Best to share the stack trace also.

Comment: i update my question and add the stackTrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to add the App Capability "networkingVpnProvider" as per the below:

[image: VPN App]

This link describes the significance and how to apply App Capabilities [MSDN App Capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations?redirectedfrom=MSDN). Ultimately you will need to add the below to your app package manifest source file (Package.appxmanifest).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package
    ...
    xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
    IgnorableNamespaces="... rescap">
...
<Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="networkingVpnProvider"/>
</Capabilities>
</Package>
```

Note that this is a Windows 10 requirement as per the documentation for the method: [VpnManagementAgent.AddProfileFromObjectAsync(IVpnProfile) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.vpn.vpnmanagementagent.addprofilefromobjectasync?view=winrt-19041#Windows_Networking_Vpn_VpnManagementAgent_AddProfileFromObjectAsync_Windows_Networking_Vpn_IVpnProfile_)

Comment: how to check the logs of Console.WriteLine("someText")

Comment: You'll find them in the `output` window in visual studio. "Ctrl+Alt+O" to open the output window.

Comment: thanks i change the console.WriteLine to System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine and its start working

Comment: how to get the status of await keyword i want to get the connectStatus

Comment: You don't get to ask "bonus questions" :) have a new question? post a new question! :)